# Toggle button in VSC not working, JavaScript code doesn't load in the console (downloaded node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, console

I am following a set of instructions from YouTube to build a blog website, this is the Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aj7HLsJenVg&t=2621s. I have also copied and pasted the completed HTML, JS, and CSS files to see if the toggle button is working and it is not.

I started noticing there was something that was not working when I did the `console.log()` to see if the `.navbar` was going to appear **but it didn't.** Also the toggle (supposedly hamburger) button did not work.

I tried downloading `node.js`, I am not sure if the JS file is actually the one that isn't working, but most functionality that I am expecting to work from its code isn't working.

**How do I make the code work?**

```js
//Grab elements
const selectElement = (selector) => {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);
    if(element) return element;
    throw new Error('Something went wrong! Make sure that ${selector} exists/is typed correctly.');
};
//couldn't get the console to work

//Nav styles on scroll
const scrollHeader = () => {
    const headerElement = selectElement('#header');
    if(this.scrollY >= 15){
        headerElement.classList.add('activated');
    }else{
        headerElement.classList.remove('activated');
    }
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHeader);
//couldn't get the test scroll work and turn red 40.47

//Open menu & search pop-up
const menuToggleIcon = selectElement('#menu-toggle-icon');

const toggleMenu = function () {
    const mobileMenu = selectElement('#menu');
    mobileMenu.classList.toggle('activated');
    menuToggleIcon.classList.toggle('activated');
};

menuToggleIcon.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
//When clicked it doesn't change anything
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1.0">

    <title>KodoSprout  |  Home</title>

    <!--Tab icon of the site-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/Images/kodoutabicon.jpeg">
    
    <!--Site Icons-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@2.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--Custom styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/main.css">
    
    <!--swiper.js styles-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Header-->
    <header class="header" id="header">

        <!--the container class will limit how wide a particular element is 
        going to stretch inside-->
        <nav class="navbar container">

            <!--logo using an anchor tag which will point/click back to the index-->
            <a href="./kodousproutindex.html">
                <h2 class="logo">KodoSprout</h2>
            </a>

            <!--the menu options, there's a list inside of this div-->
            <div class="menu" id="menu">
                <ul class="list">
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link current">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">Commentaries</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">Catalogue</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">Foodies</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">Community</a>
                    </li>   
                    <li class="list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">Snapshots</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item screen-lg-hidden">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-item screen-lg-hidden">
                        <a href="#" class="list-link">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="list list-right">
                <button class="btn place-items-center" id="theme-toggle-btn">
                    <i class="ri-sun-line sun-icon"></i>
                    <i class="ri-moon-line moon-icon"></i>
                </button>

                <button class="btn place-items-center" id="search-icon">
                    <i class="ri-search-line"></i>
                </button>

                <button class="btn place-items-center screen-lg-hidden menu-toggle-icon" id="menu-toggle-icon">
                    <i class="ri-menu-3-line open-menu-icon"></i>
                    <i class="ri-close-line close-menu-icon"></i>
                </button>

                <a href="#" class="list-link screen-sm-hidden">Contact</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-link screen-sm-hidden btn profile fancy-border">
                    <span>Profile</span>
                    </a>


            </div>

        </nav>



    </header>
</body>
</html>
```